# TyphoonPatcher for mocking in unit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, typhoon

I have `Assembly`:

```
@interface MDUIAssembly : TyphoonAssembly

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MDServiceAssembly *services;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MDModelAssembly *models;

- (id)choiceController;

@end

@implementation MDUIAssembly

- (void)resolveCollaboratingAssemblies
{
    _services = [TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy proxy];
    _models = [TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy proxy];
}

- (id)choiceController
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MDChoiceViewController class]
                          configuration: ^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithAnalytics:diary:)
                        parameters: ^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[_services analytics]];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[_models diary]];
        }];
    }];
}

@end
```

Here what I'm trying to do in tests:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    patcher = [TyphoonPatcher new];
    MDUIAssembly *ui = (id) [TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory];
    [patcher patchDefinition:[ui choiceController] withObject:^id{
       return mock([MDChoiceViewController class]);
    }];
    [[TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory] attachPostProcessor:patcher];
}

- (void) tearDown 
{
   [super tearDown];
   [patcher rollback];
}
```

Unfortunately my `setUp` fails with next message:

```
-[MDChoiceViewController key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbb8aaf0
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: we'd appreciate your input on: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Here's some extra advice to go along with the [main](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965839/404201) answer . . .***

**Unit Tests vs Integration Tests:**

In Typhoon we adhere to the traditional terms:

- **Unit Tests** : Testing your class in isolation from collaborators. This is where you inject test doubles like mocks or stubs in place of all of the real dependencies.
- **Integration Tests:** Testing your class using real collaborators. Although you may patch our a component in order to put the system in the required state for that test.

So any test that uses `TyphoonPatcher` would probably be an integration test.

More info here: [Typhoon Integration Testing](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Integration%20Testing)

**Resolve Collaborating Assemblies:**

This was required in earlier version of Typhoon, but is not longer needed. Any properties that are are sub-class of TyphoonAssembly will be treated as collaborating assemblies. Remove the following:

```
- (void)resolveCollaboratingAssemblies
{
    _services = [TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy proxy];
    _models = [TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy proxy];
}
```

**Tests instantiate their own assembly:**

We recommend that tests instantiate and tear down their on TyphoonComponentFactory. The advantages are:

- `[TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory]` is a global and has some drawbacks.
- Integration tests can define their own patches without having to worry about putting the system back in the original state.
- In addition to using TyphoonPatcher, if you wish you can create an assembly where the definitions for some components are overridden.

Comment: I pass almost all dependencies from init parameters but in one place I call Typhoon factory to proceed further. I should probably pass controller or better assembly through init as well but I think my init has already 5 dependencies. This is good smell that class is doing too much but there is no easy/clear separation. I will definitely try to simplify code. As for me writing obj-c complex code is much easier than java

Comment: It can be a smell, but *sometimes* a top-level class (eg controller) does need to orchestrate many components. It might be nice to create an object that groups several collaborators and pass that in. . alternatively, to avoid a long init method you could use property setters or method injection (well, they're options, anyway). You can override -(void)typhoonDidInject which gets called after injection, to be used in the same way you would with init - assert required state before proceeding.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach

Answer (score 3):

You've encountered a poor design choice on Typhoon's part, but there's an easy work-around.

You're using this method:

```
[patcher patchDefinition:[ui choiceController] withObject:^id{
   return mock([MDChoiceViewController class]);
}];
```

. . which is expecting a `TyphoonDefinition` as argument. When bootstrapping Typhoon:

- We start with one ore more `TyphoonAssembly` subclasses, which Typhoon instruments to obtain recipes for building components. These `TyphoonAssembly` sub-clases are then discarded.
- We now have a `TyphoonComponentFactory` that will allow any of your `TyphoonAssembly` interfaces to ***pose*** in front of it. (This is so you can have multiple configs of the same class, while still avoiding magic strings, allows auto-completion in your IDE, etc).

When the `TyphoonPatcher` was written it was designed for the case where you obtain a new `TyphoonComponentFactory` for your tests (recommended), like this:

```
//This is an actual TyphoonAssembly not the factory posing as an assembly
MiddleAgesAssembly* assembly = [MiddleAgesAssembly assembly];

TyphoonComponentFactory* factory = [TyphoonBlockComponentFactory factoryWithAssembly:assembly];

TyphoonPatcher* patcher = [[TyphoonPatcher alloc] init];
[patcher patchDefinition:[assembly knight] withObject:^id
{
    Knight* mockKnight = mock([Knight class]);
    [given([mockKnight favoriteDamsels]) willReturn:@[
        @"Mary",
        @"Janezzz"
    ]];

    return mockKnight;
}];

[factory attachPostProcessor:patcher];
Knight* knight = [(MiddleAgesAssembly*) factory knight];
```

**What happened:**

So the problem is that the `TyphoonPatcher` is expecting `TyphoonDefinition` from the `TyphoonAssembly` and instead it is getting an actual component from a `TyphoonComponentFactory`.

Very confusing, and that way of obtaining a patcher should be deprecated.

**Solution:**

Use the following instead:

```
[patcher patchDefinitionWithSelector:@selector(myController) withObject:^id{
     return myFakeController;
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for giving explanation and workaround. I saw in debug that there is no mentioning of definitions but I didn't come to this easy conclusion. I should read code more.

Comment: A number of others have had the same problem and its clear now that the API leads to confusion there, and should be fixed. So thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: Jasper, it fails in tearDown. The `_factory` is nil in postprocessor.

Comment: So looks like if patcher not used than factory is nil. As well my next tests that use factory started failing after deattaching. Looks like some issues with NSNotificationCenter. Investigating

Comment: If each integration test makes its own Typhoon patcher there should be no need to detach. Meanwhile can you please create a bug report (GitHub) for this?

Comment: I'm not sure about what exactly to create ticket - about exception if patcher is not used or about that you shouldn't not call deattach?

Comment: The variable `factory` above is unused. Why?

Comment: @fatuhoku I completed the example by using factory.